# Take a sysproperty as CLI argument for testNG Ant Target and fetch another property value using this value as Key

Tags: ant, testng, build.xml

I am trying to accomplish this.

I have a properties file which has mapping of a TestSuite business name to the actual package

test.properties
`checkout=com.mycompany.tests.checkout`

And in Ant `build.xml` I have this target defined which will invoke the TestNG Suite and I need to pass a parameter to the TestNG File

Target in build.xml

```
<target name="executeTests">
        <testng delegateCommandSystemProperties="true" haltonfailure="true" outputdir="${integ.test.dir}">
            <sysproperty key="testSuite" value="${testSuite}" />
            <classpath refid="test.classpath" />
            <xmlfileset dir="./" includes="testng/Tests.xml" />
        </testng>
</target>`
```

And the TestNG File content snippet is as below

```
    <parameter name="packageBase" value="${testSuite}" />
```

And on running target -> `ant executeTests -DtestSuite=checkout`

So far, I am successfull in passing the CLI argument in Ant build statement onto the testNG parameter,

Where I need help is, How can i use the sysProperty to read the business name of the suite and pass on the corresponding the package to TestNG XML.
I tried doing the below unsuccessfully

I tried double-resolving the testSuite variable but it doesnt work and its passed as a raw variable to the TestNG xml.

```
`<property file="testng/test.properties"/>
<target name="executeTests" depends="HappierTrails.test-integration-assert">
        <testng delegateCommandSystemProperties="true" haltonfailure="true" outputdir="${integ.test.dir}">
            <sysproperty key="testSuite" value="${testSuite}" />
            <sysproperty key="package" value="${${testSuite}}" />
            <classpath refid="test.classpath" />
            <xmlfileset dir="./" includes="testng/Tests.xml" />
        </testng>
</target>`
```

TestNG XML:
        `<parameter name="packageBase" value="${package}" />`

I get this error as the variable is not resolved

`No tests found. Check that the package base <${${testSuite}}> is correct.`

Comment: I would assume the `testng` task's nested `sysproperty`  element is setting an environment variable, not an Ant property. You can access these in Ant by first setting a prefix with the property task such as `<property environment="env" />` then referencing with `${env.testSuite}`.

Comment: Also note that Ant does not natively support double nested property references such as `${${testSuite}}`, so even if that property can be resolved, this syntax will not work.